# Fuse JS search results scoring doesn't make sense

Tags: javascript, fuse.js

I'm trying to use Fuse JS to do a fuzzy search on a list of strings but the results it's giving back don't make sense.
I've set up a playcode [here](https://playcode.io/634949/) as an example.

Here my list is

```
[
   "Yoga with Adriene - Revolution",
   "Brewdog beers",
   "NBA teams seen live",
   "Yoga with Adriene - DEDICATE - 30 days",
   "Yoga with Adriene - home",
]
```

My code config is

```
const options = {
  isCaseSensitive: false,
  includeScore: true,
  shouldSort: true,
};
```

When I search with search term 'yoga home'
The closest match returned is 'Brewdog beers' which is clearly the worst search result, I'm expecting it to return the 'Yoga with Adriene - home' result first with 2 words matching.
The results are:

```
[
  {
    "item": "Brewdog beers",
    "refIndex": 1,
    "score": 0.6932183529538054
  },
  {
    "item": "Yoga with Adriene - Revolution",
    "refIndex": 0,
    "score": 0.6959441913889373
  },
  {
    "item": "Yoga with Adriene - home",
    "refIndex": 4,
    "score": 0.6959441913889373
  },
  {
    "item": "Yoga with Adriene - DEDICATE - 30 days",
    "refIndex": 3,
    "score": 0.7504597227725356
  }
]
```

Where a score of 0 is an exact match.

Comment: I know I am late to the party, but did you figure this out? I am trying to make sense of my results too.

Comment: I didn't no, I moved to fuzzy-search instead which made a bit more sense